# Could not create an acl object: Invalid XML in file

Tags: magento2.2, xml, acl

Hello I've this custom module for Magento when loggin in to Magento Admin I am getting this error

Error Message I am getting

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl
>   object: Invalid XML in file
>   /home/web/public_html/app/code/Pmage/Matrixprice/etc/acl.xml: Element
>   'config', attribute
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation':
>   The attribute
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation'
>   is not allowed. Line: 2
>
> Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid
>   XML in file
>   /home/web/public_html/app/code/Pmage/Matrixprice/etc/acl.xml: Element
>   'config', attribute
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation':
>   The attribute
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation'
>   is not allowed. Line: 2

The Code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">
               <!--AddMenuAcl-->
                   <resource id="Pmage_Unit::unit"  title="Pmage">
                        <resource id="Pmage_Matrixprice::manage_matrix" title="Manage Matrix" />
                    </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance` with `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Notice the extra dash (-) between Schema and instance.

Comment: That didnt do it. I think

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid XML in file /home/web/public_html/app/code/Pmage/Unit/etc/acl.xml:
Element 'config', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed.
Line: 2

Comment: clear the cache. As I can see, nothing changed.

Comment: Did that too,, nothing changed same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect: `<resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">`

Should be: `<resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">`

Answer (score 1):

> Change this line, your module name is incorrect.

```
<resource id="Pmage_Unit::unit"  title="Pmage">
```

> Update code

```
<resource id="Pmage_Matrixprice::unit"  title="Pmage">
```

**Hope it helps.**